# Error when attempting to check if page exists or not (function returns undefined)

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to check if a URL exists or not. The function is supposed to return true if the url is not 404, and false if it is 404'd.

Now for some reason this function is returning "undefined"

Here is my code:

```
function checkURL(url){
    var xmlhttp; // initialize the request object
    // All the browsers except for the old IE
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //old IE
    }
    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.open("HEAD", url, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status!=404) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362462/how-can-i-make-xhr-onreadystatechange-return-its-result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make XHR.onreadystatechange return its result?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362462/how-can-i-make-xhr-onreadystatechange-return-its-result)

Comment: because it is async operation!!!

Comment: Those answers were not very helpful. I need to check whether it is 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of checkURL will be undefined until the AJAX request finishes. I would approach this with a callback like this:

```
function checkURL(url, cb) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url, true);

    request.onload = function() {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        cb(true)
      } else {
        cb(false)
      }
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      cb(false)
    };

    request.send();
}


checkURL('https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript.json', function(status) {
    if (status) {
        // did not 404
    } else {
        // 404 or error
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank-you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I had no idea a callback was required. Cheers!

Comment: I was just looking through my older questions as the problem did arise in my newer code and I realized that this does not work for cross domain because of the Cross Orgin Request policy. eg: you cannot use this code for reddit.com unless you have access to it or run it in the javascript console. This is not exactly what I am looking for in my software.